# How to send and read just two integer values in one time with UDP?

Tags: java, android, udp

I'm working on an Android Client and a Java Server app. I've sent and received a String but I need sending two integer values in one time. Should I use integer array just two integer? Values will like these : int value_1 = 5; int value_2 = -10;  I'm sending String like this ;

Android Client:

```
             command = "hello";
        dp = new DatagramPacket(command.getBytes(),command.length(), serverAddr,  this.port);
        ds.send(dp);
```

...
Java Server at PC

```
   message= new byte[1024]; 
      dp  = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
      ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
   ds.receive(dp);
     receive= new String(message, 0, dp.getLength());
```

I've searched about this , I didn't get it any thing. How can I send two integer values in one time, and how can I read it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest serializing your integer data into a json string, sending it as a string the way you already are, and then converting it back on the server side.

Here's an example:

```
    // client side code
    int[] clientArray = { 5, -10 };
    String command = new Gson().toJson(clientArray);
    dp = new DatagramPacket(command.getBytes(), command.length(), serverAddr, this.port);
    ds.send(dp);

    // server side code
    message = new byte[1024];
    dp = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
    ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
    ds.receive(dp);
    receive = new String(message, 0, dp.getLength());
    int[] serverArray = new Gson().fromJson(command, int[].class);
```